# Game: removing coins from two stacks.

Tags: number-theory, puzzle

Two Players $A$ & $B$ starts to play game, they play turn by turn, A goes first.

They start with two stacks of $N$ number of coins each, Each player either have to remove one coin each from both of the stacks or remove as much coins ( more than or equal to $1$ ) as he want from any one of those stacks.

The one who makes last move wins.

Given Number of coins in each stack i.e $N$ , can you tell who will win this game if both plays optimally.

Comment: $N$ is the number of coins in both stacks, or we are given both $N_1$ and $N_2$ the number ofcoins on each stack?

Comment: Two stacks each with N number of coins

Comment: Just a few thoughts on winning positions: - Whoever emptys one stack loses (The other player just takes all remaining coins from the other stack) - Whoever reaches $(1,1)$ loses (The other player takes one coin from each). I have a feeling that the winning strategy depends on the parity of $N$.

Comment: Well, this game is known as Nim pile game. (You can find more of it from its wikipedia page. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible moves are

(1 - n) take n coins of the pile 1
(2 - n)take n coins of the pile 2
(3) take one coin of both piles

The trick in this game is to give your player one of the following kinds of patterns:

(a) N ; N
(b) N + 1; N + 2
(c) N + 2; N + 1

Where $N$ represents a multiple of 3 (can be 0. In those positions, the other player cannot win in one round, and we can always answer them in such a way we can give them another piles of those kinds.

We will represent B as the player with the winning strategy, and gives to player A one of the referred positions, wlog (a): if A plays (3), B takes one coin, if A plays (1 - n) or (2- n), the:

if n=1 mod 3, B plays n+1 on the other stack

if n=2 mod 3, B plays n-1 on the other stack

if n=0 mod 3, B plays n on the other stack

In that fashion, B always leaves the game in one of the winning kinds. For (b) and (c), the strategy is similar.

Summing up:

Suppose $N$ is 1 module 3, then A has to use (3) and plays as I explain after, having the winning strategy.

Suppose $N$ is 2 module 3, then A has to use (1 - 1) or (2 - 1), i.e. has to take one coin from a pile at choice. Then plays as I explain after, having the winning strategy.

If $3|N$, then B can always answer

Answer (score 0):

If $N_1=N_2$, A loses, if not, then all A have to do is to equalize the stacks. In this fashion B is forced to uneven the stacks and A will have the last move for sure.

So, as both stacks have the same number of coins, A will lose if B plays well.

Comment: I've made it clear that They start with two stacks, each of them having N number of coins.

Comment: As A is forced to unequalize the staks, B will equalize them. If this goes on A will have no chance of winning, because he always receives two piles of coins. As the number of coins is always descending, there will be a time where B will receive only one stack of coins ( the other has 0 coins ) and wins.

Comment: What if N=2, 
A will take one coin from one stack.. Now B has to play with one stack having 1 coin and another stack with two coins... No matter what he does A wins

Comment: I totally forgotten about the move of taking a coin of both of the piles. Then the answer would be module 3. A wins if N is not divisible by 3. I will arrange an answer.

Comment: Moreover both of them optimally